# Virtualization Technology Not Supported while Installing HAXM

Tags: android, cpu, virtualization, intel, haxm

I want to install HAXM on windows 8.1 (HP pavilion 3515) (I've downloaded the hotfix from [here](http://software.intel.com/ru-ru/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)). but the below error occurs during installation  (HyperV is not installed on my laptop). so I installed the "Intel processor utility to check if my laptop supports VT or not, and as you see in the second picture it says "NO". then I checked my bios and I saw "Virtualization technology" item in "configuration manager" tab! and I enabled it, and tried to install HAXM again, but I got the error again and I saw NO in front of "Virtualization technology again. 
Now my question is that "is there any way to do so my cup can support it"? or it's a hardware problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ark.intel.com](http://ark.intel.com/products/35581/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5800-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB), the T5900 series processors do not support VT-x. Not sure why your bios indicates that you have it.  Perhaps it supports some VT features but not all the VT features that HAXM requires.

Here are some trouble-shooting tips for installing HAXM.
http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware problem. If your CPU doesn't support Intel Virtualization Technology then HAXM will not work for you.