# VT not supported while installing HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to install intelhaxm-android in my machine. It is giving me error VT-x not supported in my computer (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429536/virtualization-technology-not-supported-while-installing-haxm) too)
I tried every solution given there:

- Enabled Virtualization from BIOS
- Turned off the Hyper-V by cmd line
- Enabled Execute Disable bit (as suggested on [intel guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm))

It is not working out for me. Please someone help, what could be the possible problem in my case, and if someone could suggest a solution, would be great.

My machine is HP Pavilion g4 Notebook PC/Windows 7 Home Basic 64-bit/AMD A4-3330MX APU

Comment: Please Check if VT is on with this small tool: https://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade the processor upper than Core 2 Duo @3.9 GHz E7500. I can install this software (HAXM) on my PC, but I cannot use it, because of my processor doesn't strong enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It caused by your APU/CPU type. From Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) [official website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x):

> **Important:**
>   Intel HAXM cannot be used on systems without an Intel processor, or with an Intel processor that lacks the hardware features described in the "Hardware Requirements" section above.To determine the capabilities of your Intel processor, visit http://ark.intel.com/
>   Additionally, Intel HAXM can be used only with Android* x86 emulator images provided by Intel. Intel HAXM cannot be used with ARM* Android* emulator images or non-Intel x86 Android* emulator images.

But your processor is AMD, not Intel. It means, you need to upgrade your Notebook PC's processor to Intel.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to install software for intel processor, but you have AMD. According to Android emulator [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).

> Virtual machine acceleration for Windows requires the installation of the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel HAXM). The software requires an Intel CPU with Virtualization Technology (VT) support.

So you basically need Intel processor for x86 virtualization.

In you case I'd recommend you to use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) emulator. It usually works faster than native Android emulator with HAXM and uses Virtualbox virtualization technology, so can be run on your processor. It's also cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I installed Genymotion (even with Virtual box). Now genymotion gives me same error that virtualization is not supported in my computer. I guess upgrading to intel processor is the only solution.

Comment: It shouldn't be. I work with AMD on my home computer and Intel at work. Both work good. The issue should be not with the processor brand, but the settings or hardware itself. You either didn't enable virtualization or your processor do not support all aspects of virtualization virtualbox needs.

Comment: I enabled the virtualization from BIOS, may be it does not support all virtualization aspects then.